# Out of memory: Killed process (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, python-itertools

```
import time
import itertools
from itertools import product
list_1 = ["PGNGVG","PGNRVG","PRNGVG","PRNRVG","PGNGVR","PGNRVR","PRNGVR","PRNRVR","PGNEVG","PGNEVR","PRNEVG","PRNEVR","PENGVG","PENGVR","PENRVG","PENRVR"]

list_2 = ['G','R','NOC']
unique_combinations = list(list(zip(list_1, element))  for element in product(list_2, repeat = len(list_1)))

print((unique_combinations[1]))
```

When i execute the above with two values in list_2 , It executes . But when executed with 3 values i get the message "killed" from OS

> Jan 27 15:34:15 ip-172-31-25-60 kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=python3,pid=19290,uid=1000

I tried collecting memory using gc.collect() and using deque instead of list .

Comment: Your `list_1` has length 16. Using `itertools.product` with a list of size 2 and repeat  = 16 will generate `2**16` combinations or 65,536 combinations. However, increasing it to a list of size 3 will get you 43,046,721 combinations, about 650x more. If you are planning to store every one of these combinations, then I don't think memory management is going to help.

Comment: What if i dont want to store but do some operation on every outcome ?

Comment: Can you help me with the code